# Hapi complains about a missing plugin dependency that is installed

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

When starting my program, I get:

```
Error: Plugin routes-api-cruises missing dependency @hapi/nes
    at new module.exports (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/error.js:23:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as assert] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/assert.js:20:11)
    at module.exports.internals.Core._validateDeps (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/core.js:348:22)
    at module.exports.internals.Core._initialize (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/core.js:320:14)
    at module.exports.internals.Core._start (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/core.js:240:24)
    at internals.Server.start (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/server.js:523:27)
    at startServer (/usr/src/app/server.js:12:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
```

I don't know whether "Plugin *x* missing dependency *y*" means the plugin fails to *declare* the dependency it uses, or whether the declared dependency is not *installed*.

It looks like the plugin declares its dependency:

```js
exports.plugin = {
  name: 'routes-api-cruises',
  dependencies: ['hapi-mongodb', '@hapi/nes'],  // <- there it is
  ...
}
```

It also looks like the package is installed:

```
$ find node_modules -iname 'nes'
node_modules/@hapi/nes
```

And `package.json` includes:

```js
"dependencies": {
   "@hapi/nes": "^11.2.1",
   ...
}
```

And `package-lock.json` includes:

```js
@hapi/nes": {
      "version": "11.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@hapi/nes/-/nes-11.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-XGFfTQsBB7NnpIgVdnz36lrZjJlUgni0tLmcN4TWiYdCGxNr6+YRreQ6jdsGN3j8qfZ8yLBY0FsGkHBiMPKLAw==",
      ...
}
```

The code uses `@hapi/glue`'s `compose()` function and passes in a list of plugins to register and `@hapi/nes` is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [source of that error](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/v18.3.0/lib/core.js#L342) in the Hapi source code and used the Node inspector to attach a breakpoint there.

The function `_validateDeps` enumerates the dependencies declared by each plugin. It looks these up in `this.registrations`, a map of plugin registrations.

In `this.registrations`, `@hapi/nes` shows up as simply `nes`. Changing the plugin dependency declaration to simply `nes` makes the lookup work.